# How do I fetch the hourly average CPUUtilization for my cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, amazonica

I would like to be able to fetch the hourly average CPUUtilization for my cluster. But using amazonica I get this error: `com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.InvalidParameterValueException: The parameter StartTime must not equal parameter EndTime.`

```
(get-metric-statistics {:metric-name "CPUUtilization"
                        :namespace "AWS/ECS"
                        :dimensions [{:name  "ClusterName" :value "my-cluster"}]
                        :start-time "2018-08-31T12:00:00Z"
                        :end-time "2018-08-31T13:00:00Z"
                        :statistics ["Average"]
                        :period 3600})
```

Running this aws cmd returns the correct metric, but I want to use amazonica to do this.

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics \
--metric-name CPUUtilization \
--namespace AWS/ECS \
--dimensions Name=ClusterName,Value=my-cluster \
--start-time 2018-08-31T12:00:00Z \
--end-time 2018-08-31T13:00:00Z \
--statistics Average \
--period 3600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/GetMetricStatisticsRequest.html) :start-time and :end-time must be a Date object. It does not work with string in your example. You can also take a look at this [example](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica/blob/master/test/amazonica/test/cloudwatch.clj#L22)

```
(let [date-string (.. (SimpleDateFormat. "MM-dd-yyyy")
                  (format (Date.)))]
   (get-metric-statistics
       ....
       :start-time (.minusDays (DateTime.) 1)
       :end-time date-string
       ...
      ))
```

Comment: I think non-date values also work; in fact Freid001 found out that the following is also a way to go: `:start-time (t/minus (t/now) (t/hours 1)) :end-time (t/now)`